# Match value in an array in Php

Tags: php

I have these values in an array which are below showing.

```
$arrayOfId

Array

 (
                    [0] => 45 
                    [1] => 41 
                    [2] => 33 
                    [3] => 42 
                    [4] => 42 
                    [5] => 42 
                    [6] => 42 
                    [7] => 42 
                    [8] => 42 
                    [9] => 42 

                )
```

and matching a specific value in an array.

```
**PHP**

    $user_id = $row['user_id'];
    //comming user id in $row result is $user_id= 42;

    if(in_array($user_id,$arrayOfId))
    { 
    echo "Already exist";
    }else
    {
    echo "Not exist";
    }
```

Strange it is not going in true block. going to false.

i am getting result via Ajax.
Why ?

Comment: Dump the value of `$share_id1`, then we can help better

Comment: $share_id1 is now $arrayOfId

Comment: is this just a typing mistake? `echo"Already exist";`

Comment: yes its just a typing mistake

Answer (score 3):

```
$arrayOfId  = Array
(
    0 => 45,
    1 => 41, 
    2 => 33, 
    3 => 42,
    4 => 42, 
    5 => 42, 
    6 => 42, 
    7 => 42, 
    8 => 42, 
    9 => 42 

);

$user_id = 52;

if(in_array($user_id,$arrayOfId))
{
   echo "Already exist";
}
else
{
  echo "Not exist";
}
```

This is working perfectly fine. I didn't found any problem in you code. Check whether $arrayOfId is the array.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to do the `var_dump()` for both `$user_id` and `$share_id1` variables. It looks like you spelled the variable name wrong. Another option is that you got an object instead of array when converting from JSON.

Comment: With var_dump();

Please ignore the array value which are not entered in question. value. 
  

array(15) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "45 "
  [1]=>
  string(3) "41 "
  [2]=>
  string(3) "33 "
  [3]=>
  string(3) "42 "
  [4]=>
  string(3) "42 "
  [5]=>
  string(3) "33 "
  [6]=>
  string(3) "42 "
  [7]=>
  string(3) "42 "
  [8]=>
  string(3) "42 "
  [9]=>
  string(3) "42 "
  [10]=>
  string(3) "42 "
  [11]=>
  string(3) "42 "
  [12]=>
  string(3) "42 "
  [13]=>
  string(3) "42 "
  [14]=>
  string(0) ""
}

Comment: Thank you. Now it is clear what is wrong. You compare 3 characters string like '42 ' with string '42' and they are not equal. Please to var_dump() for $user_id. Is this a string or an integer?

Comment: Hey Mr. Victor , according to comment of user, i think there is coming problem with quotes or space in user's code. if i am thinking right.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the Value of your array as well as $row['user_id'], code works fine.

```
$array   = array(45 ,41,33,42,42,42,42,42,42 );
$user_id = 42;//$row['user_id'];                    
if(in_array($user_id,$array)){
  echo "It is coming";
}
```